# Add DateTimeField to existing Django model

Tags: python, datetime, django-models, alter

I am trying to add 2 date fields (target_date & actual_date) to the existing model. Already there is a date field (*report_date*) in the existing table.

Default values for these fields(target_date & actual_date) should be 5 days more than *report_date*.

My codes are given below.

***Models.py***

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import date, time, datetime
import datetime


class qc2_report_table(models.Model):
    report_date = models.DateTimeField( auto_now_add=True ) # Existing field
    target_date = models.DateTimeField() # New field to be added
    actual_date = models.DateTimeField() # New field to be added
```

I tried various options and I am getting the below error.

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC
> Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]ALTER TABLE only allows columns
> to be added that can contain nulls, or have a DE FAULT definition
> specified, or the column being added is an identity or timestamp
> column, or alternatively if none of the previous conditions are
> satisfied the table must be empty to allo w addition of this column.
> Column 'actual_date' cannot be added to non-empty
> table 'app1_qc2_report_table' because it does not satisfy these
> conditions. (4901) (SQLEx ecDirectW)")

Answer (score 0):

After removing all the migration files (other than 0001_initial.py), I am able to migrate. I don't know the reason behind the error, but this fix worked for me.